# Is data driven testing possible with protractor?

Tags: angularjs, automation, protractor

What I would like to achieve is for the Protractor tests to extract data from a separate data file (e.g CSV, JSON, etc) so that I could change the data without having to touch the test script code.

Is this possible with Protractor?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `browser.params` to read custom test data.

To read from a JSON file simply add `params` to your [config file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/a368de0b74db35a90d9a2d8aa48a7e57a45a2aa7/spec/basicConf.js#L23)

```
exports.config = {
  params: require('./your-params-file.json'),
};
```

NodeJS will automatically convert the JSON file to a Javascript object that is easily accessible from any of your tests through `browser.params.whateverYourJSONHas`.

If you really need to use CSV then try some parser like [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.org/package/csvtojson) or google / open another question about "NodeJS convert CSV file to array of POJOs"

Comment: @RustyWizard if this is a solution for you, you can flag it answered. it turns green, other users know somebody confirmed it's working, and elgalu gets some pixel points ;)

Comment: @elgalu I will definitely do so. Shortly after I posted this question I got a slightly higher priority task assigned to me. I will look into this as soon as I'm done with that.

Comment: My previous was in reply to @nilsK; sorry if it cause any confusion. 

That said, thanks @elgalu. Your answer did help. However instead of specifying it on the config file, I specified it in the spec file as `browser.params = require('../data.json');` as I felt this will give me the flexibility of having different files associated to different spec files rather than storing everything in one file and reading that the whole of that particular file. Is there by any chance a better approach to this?

Comment: @RustyWizard: Your approach is seemingly beneficial to me. However, when I try to use    browser.params = require('../data.json'); in my test file, I can't really get it working for different data files for different tests! Did you work with different data files for different tests?

Comment: Hey..is it possible to read multiple json files in require? Something like: params: require('./file1.json','./file2.json'),

Comment: @LeoGallucci/@RustyWizard: Can you please help me with the above query!

Comment: `require('./file1.json','./file2.json')` doesn't work. Just use a loop (for/while/forEach/..) Please open a new question if you don't know how to do a js loop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you were able to figure this out or not. however, I was able to accomplish just this.

Here's what your json might look like:

```
[ 
    {
        "someId": "signInInput",
        "sendSomeKeys": "j@j.com"
    },
    {
        "someId": "passwordInput",
        "sendSomeKeys": "password"
    }
]
```

And here's how to implement it in your test:

```
'use strict';

var testData = require('./path/to/json.json');

describe('your test', function() {
    testData.forEach( function (data) {
        it('should read from an external json', function(){
            element(by.id(data.someId)).sendKeys(data.sendSomeKeys);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may simply iterate using javascript "map" function without any loops:

```
var testParams = testConfig.testArray;

testParams.map(function(testSpec) {
    it('write your test here', function() {
        //test code here
    });
});
```